# Error occurred while refresh the page in Mean Stack2

Tags: angular2-routing, mean-stack

I just try to create a project in mean stack2.
But, I got a error message 'Cannot GET/User' while refresh the browser as follow.
How can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the following code inside @NgModule decorator in app.module.ts class.

```
providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}]
```

import locationStategry and HashLocationStatregry from @angular/common

```
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from "@angular/common"
```